# Fixing 'obsolete' warning when using MsgPack.Cli

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-warnings, msgpack

I'm using MsgPack.Cli to write a custom serializer for a Session class I have created. After creating the class using [this tutorial on the MsgPack.Cli github page](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli/blob/master/samples/Samples/Sample04_CustomSerializer.cs), I receive this warning:

> Warning: 'MessagePackSerializer.MessagePackSerializer()' is obsolete: 'Use MessagePackSerializer(SerializationContext) instead.'

I cannot work out what change would fix this warning. I don't think knowledge of MessagePackSerializer is necessary to help me with this; I simply do not understand the syntax of the warning.

My code is included below:

```
namespace Something_Networky
{
    public class Session
    {
        private int _n;
        public int n { get; }

        public Session(int n)
        {
            this._n = n;
        }
    }

    public class SessionSerializer : MessagePackSerializer<Session>
    {
        public SessionSerializer() : this(SerializationContext.Default) { }

        public SessionSerializer(SerializationContext context) // Warning displayed on this line
        {

        }

        protected override void PackToCore(Packer packer, Session value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override Session UnpackFromCore(Unpacker unpacker)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the error. The working code is below; I wasn't calling the base constructor with the correct arguments.

```
public class SessionSerializer : MessagePackSerializer<Session>
{
    public SessionSerializer(SerializationContext context) : base(context) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void PackToCore(Packer packer, Session objectTree)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override Session UnpackFromCore(Unpacker unpacker)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```